# Python - How to process nested dictionaries written as strings in a Dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, string, pandas, dictionary

I'm running into a problem which I found similar to other examples on the plateform but not quite the same.

My dataframe is based on a CSV of sensor data.

Here is the output of only one cell :

```
df['streams'][0]
```

out :

```
> "{'AirBeam-PM': {'session_id': 83611, 'measurements_count': 1904,
> 'unit_name': 'micrograms per cubic meter', 'sensor_name':
> 'AirBeam-PM', 'threshold_medium': 35, 'size': 1904, 'max_longitude':
> 105.8774276, 'sensor_package_name': 'AirBeam:00189610582E', 'unit_symbol': 'µg/m³', 'measurement_short_type': 'PM',
> 'average_value': 23.6113, 'start_longitude': 105.8773687,
> 'threshold_very_high': 150, 'min_latitude': 21.014873333,
> 'threshold_very_low': 0, 'measurement_type': 'Particulate Matter',
> 'threshold_high': 55, 'start_latitude': 21.0243842, 'min_longitude':
> 105.854333333, 'max_latitude': 21.040161667, 'id': 292691, 'threshold_low': 12}, 'AirBeam-RH': {'session_id': 83611,
> 'measurements_count': 1904, 'unit_name': 'percent', 'sensor_name':
> 'AirBeam-RH', 'threshold_medium': 50, 'size': 1904, 'max_longitude':
> 105.8774276, 'sensor_package_name': 'AirBeam:00189610582E', 'unit_symbol': '%', 'measurement_short_type': 'RH', 'average_value':
> 52.0557, 'start_longitude': 105.8773687, 'threshold_very_high': 100, 'min_latitude': 21.014873333, 'threshold_very_low': 0,
> 'measurement_type': 'Humidity', 'threshold_high': 75,
> 'start_latitude': 21.0243842, 'min_longitude': 105.854333333,
> 'max_latitude': 21.040161667, 'id': 292690, 'threshold_low': 25},
> 'AirBeam-F': {'session_id': 83611, 'measurements_count': 1904,
> 'unit_name': 'degrees Fahrenheit', 'sensor_name': 'AirBeam-F',
> 'threshold_medium': 50, 'size': 1904, 'max_longitude': 105.8774276,
> 'sensor_package_name': 'AirBeam:00189610582E', 'unit_symbol': 'F',
> 'measurement_short_type': 'F', 'average_value': 83.7983,
> 'start_longitude': 105.8773687, 'threshold_very_high': 100,
> 'min_latitude': 21.014873333, 'threshold_very_low': 0,
> 'measurement_type': 'Temperature', 'threshold_high': 75,
> 'start_latitude': 21.0243842, 'min_longitude': 105.854333333,
> 'max_latitude': 21.040161667, 'id': 292692, 'threshold_low': 25}}"
```

As you can see, there is a larger dictionary encompassing different dictionaries but it's all  written as a massive string which means I can't use any of the usual dict keys and I don't know what to make of it.

The end goal would be to have a dataframe created from the output of each cell, that is each dict in the pandas Series written in a dataframe.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks

Comment: Does `pd.DataFrame(eval(df['streams'][0]))` work?

Comment: if not eval, give json.loads(...) a try

Comment: @ecortazar see my answer below, I get an error for both, same with yaml

Comment: I copied the string you posted and did pd.DataFrame(eval(s)). It worked perfectly. It seems the problem elsewhere in the data.